# Can these things be done at home on a hobbyist budget?

Tags: mycology, microscopy, parasitology

I've toyed with getting into microscopy as a hobby for fun and potentially practical reasons. Can anyone tell me whether or not these are doable at home in 2023 with a \$500 to \$1000 budget?

1. Identifying random molds (on surfaces, on foods)
2. Seeing what's in dust? (mites, mold?)
3. Looking for and identifying parasites in animals or soil samples (worms in feces, fleas or fungi on skin or hooves)
4. Looking for metal shavings in engine oils (maybe not appropriate for this forum, worth a shot anyway)

Quick googling led me to something like the swift sw380t with a camera for around \$500 + some equipment for slides. Being able record is particularly attractive. Is that reasonable? Is it overkill? Underkill? Should I just grab something used off fb marketplace for a fraction of the cost?

Comment: With a middle-price optical microscope (I would consider the sw380t to be mid-price), you can get up to about 1000x useful magnification. Look for a microscope with a 100x oil immersion objective. 1000x will allow you to resolve objects down to a few microns - this would include almost all fungi and animals, but not bacteria. A lower end microscope will be able to see almost all fungi and animals as well, but thinner fungi and fungi spores will be harder to see.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend getting a microscope off of craigslist or marketplace. It probably won't be as good as the same microscope new, but it will be much better than a new microscope for the same price.

Comment: @Eonema 1000x is certainly enough to see bacteria - they are typically 1-5 microns in diameter, which is well within the optical resolution of a microscope.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks for the correction, I guess my microscope is just in poor condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no as to bacterial and fungal samples. For these you need a conventional light microscope that transmits the light through the sample. These are the common ones when people consider microscopes. You can also get reflected light microscopes (and even hybrid versions for hobbyists), that are needed if you are looking at solid objects such as fleas. These are sometimes called dissection microscopes and generally have lower magnifications (10-200x) only. I don't see why you wouldn't be able to see metal shavings in engine oil, with a conventional microscope, though getting enough light through the sample might be a problem there. Don't get oil on the lenses though and be wary of scratching your lens with any metal shavings if you do.

The key with microscopes is quality of the lenses (not surprisingly) - the better the lens, the fewer aberrations you get in the image, both in colour distortion and spherical (shape) aberration. Mid-range microscopes, price-wise, tend not to be the greatest at lens productions, but are certainly suitable for general use - and you may also be able to buy better lenses and swap them on. In this group I would include manufacturers such as Swift and Celestron. The top-end microscope makers such as Olympus and Zeiss are typically much more expensive, but worth it, if you can find a good one second-hand.

For bacteria you need 1000x (100x objective with 10x eyepiece) to see any details, but they are visible at 400x, if you know what you are doing. However, you need a lot of bacteria to do this, as I explain below.

Generally for ID purposes and even just to visualize bacteria, you would need to stain the sample. This involves a bunch of chemicals (iodine, potassium hydroxide etc.) and stains (Giemsa, Saffronin, Toludine blue, Malachite green etc.) that won't be available to the home hobbyist, though there might be alternatives to these that home hobbyists have worked out and/or are available (e.g. crystal violet, part of the Gram stain, is gentian violet used to treat skin infections sometimes, so chemists/pharmacies have it). Food dyes work in some situations.

You also generally need a pure isolate to look at, though you can do mixed floral growths off medium that might work. Just taking something like skin and looking for bacteria or fungi won't work as they aren't abundant enough to see easily. In a proper lab, bacteria and fungi are grown on a solid medium (agar plate - you can think of this as a jelly with nutrients) and scraped off. Generally not done straight from a sample as this is difficult and has lots of other things in there that interfere with the microscopy. That's not to say you can't do it, just it is more difficult!

Having said that, you can look at all sorts of things under a light microscope that don't require high magnifications or any expertise to look at - pond water being the classic. This will be full of small protozoa ([amoeba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba), [paramecium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramecium), [rotifers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotifer) etc) and algae that look great and are really fun to ID at 100-400x magnifications.

Cheek cells (use the round end of a toothpick to gently scrape the inside of your cheek, fix gently over a flame, stain with crystal violet) look great, and you can see a bunch of internal structures with 400x magnification.

Cross sections of leaves (hold between two thin pieces of polystyrene or cork and slice gently with a new single-edge razor blade or craft knife). . These will show the internal structure of the leaves - veins (xylem, phloem), cells etc. You can also use clear nailpolish to paint on the surface of a leaf (try the underside), then peel off and look at under the microscope - this should let you see the pores (called [stomata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoma)) in detail, they look like pairs of lips usually. The fine tissue skin (not the brown bit, it's a very thin wet translucent bit) of an onion also looks pretty nice. Moss leaves also are fun to look at.

Along with mosses - take some dry moss, let it sit in water for 30 min or so and then squeeze out - you'll hopefully find [tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade)

Edited to add:

With respect to parasites in faeces; this requires a bit of expertise to get good at. There is a lot of matter in faeces and parasites are generally low abundance. Unless you know a host is infected and are willing to mix faeces with water, filter and do a bunch of screening, you might not find any actual parasites, though you might see things that look, to the untrained eye, like parasites but are really just debris. You also run a significant chance of infecting yourself with something, be it parasitic, bacterial or viral.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! It sounds like a lot of fun. I wasn't sure if there might be some infection/contamination risks around looking for parasites. I had assumed that preparing slides would involve mixing and processing, but I am completely ignorant to the logistics of doing that safely. How likely is it that a reasonably motivated hobbyist could learn how to do this safely? or is that something best left to the pros?

Comment: @Shaun I would leave the parasites to the pros, though it seems that you only need a couple of milligrams of faeces with water on a slide to see something. So long as you wore gloves, face mask and eye-protection. I think you would be fine. For the fungi - scrape some off bread or jam and have a look. These are generally harmless to humans.